Partitioning Cellular Prism Operator?
In singular homology, we have the prism operator
$P : C_{n}(X) \rightarrow C_{n+1}(Y)$ between singular chains, and for a (singular) $n$-simplex $\sigma$, $P(\sigma)$ decomposes into $(n+1)$ simplices
(We just partition $\Delta^n \times I$ into $(n+1)$ simplices and write down the formula just like in Hatcher's book).
Is there a similar result for cellular prism operator?
That is, for a CW complex $X$ and $Y$, and say we have $f, g : X \rightarrow Y$ are cellular maps and are homotopic. So we have a cellular homotopy between them.
By this answer,
Cellular prism operator
this induces a cellular prism operator $Q : C_{n}^{CW}(X) \rightarrow C_{n+1}^{CW}(Y)$. Then, can we have a kind of decomposition like in the case of singular chains, say the number of cells in $Q(\sigma)$ for an $n$-cell $\sigma$?
(Here $C_{n}^{CW}$ means cellular chain complex)

It's not clear what you want that isn't given in the linked answer. Do you want to have an explicit description of this isomorphism $C(X\times I)\cong C(X)\otimes C(I)$? Or are you expecting an explicit formula along the lines of $Q=\sum_i[\text{some stuff}]$ as it is in the simplicial case?

The linked answer just gives the formula for the cellular prism operator. Yes, if there is a formula like $Q = \sum_i$ [some stuff] as it is in the simplicial case, that would be great.

Or perhaps some way of counting the number of cells that are in the brackets in the above sum in the comment.

I can't really remember how it goes but if you can understand a formula for $C(X)\otimes C(I)\cong C(X\times I)$ that could be useful

That isomorphism comes from the product cell structure. So then there's just one cell in the sum? Something doesn't feel right....

No. $C(X)\otimes C(I)$ 's $n$th object is $\bigoplus_{k=0}^n C_k(X)\otimes C_{n-k}(I)$. The typical element is a sum of stuff

You are right that it is a sum of stuff as you've written. But... $I$ is just a 1-cell. And in cellular chains $C_{n}^{CW}(X)$, the basis are the $n$-cells. Hence $C_{k}^{CW}(I) = 0$ for $k \geq 2$. Which believes me to think that it depends on its CW structure or something...
